# Is there a way to view the entire content inside of scrollview graphically in android 4.0+?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, configuration, scrollview

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138982/view-entire-content-of-scrollview-in-eclipses-graphical-layout) however it does not seem to work within android/eclipse sdk 4.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to try to work with [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), has a very good graphic designer.

Comment: You're welcome @Tukajo, really JetBrains and Google is a really good combination :)