# Issues creating layouts in landscape mode android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, graphical-layout-editor

I am creating layouts for and application in landscape mode and the layouts are big enough so have wrapped everything in scrollview.But main problem I'm facing is to arrange align the layouts which is out of the screen area as it is not visible in graphical layout.

Following is the code for layout and in the code the relative layout with Id:`@+id/lastjobRL` and the views after that are going out of the screen in graphical layout mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboardtxtLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_header_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e9f5fe"
        android:padding="@dimen/dashboard_header_txt_padding"
        android:text="@string/dashboard"
        android:textColor="#35617d"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_txt_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/separator_img_description"
        android:src="@drawable/job_details_separator" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardSV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#e9f5fe"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dashboard_sv_paddingbottom"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboardLV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dashboard_lv_marginbottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_lv_marginbottom" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/SectionBackgrondIMG"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/SectionBackgrond_img_margintop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/SectionBackgrond_img"
                android:src="@drawable/sections_background_2x" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectionHZ"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_hz_margintop"
                android:gravity="top" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myjobIMG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myjob_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/myjob_img_marginleft"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/myjob_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/my_jobs" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/diaryIMG"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/diary_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/diary" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timesheetsIMG"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/timesheets_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timesheets_img_marginleft"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/timesheets_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/timesheet" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reddotHZ"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reddpt_hz_margintop"
                android:gravity="top" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myjobreddotIMG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myjob_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/myjob_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/myjobreddot_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myjobreddotTXT"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/myjob_reddot_txt_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myjob_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/myjob_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/myjob_reddot_txt_margintop"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/myjob_reddot_text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/timesheets_txt_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/diaryreddotIMG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/diary_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/diary_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/diaryreddot_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/diaryreddotTXT"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/diary_reddot_txt_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/diary_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/diary_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/diary_reddot_txt_margintop"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/diary_reddot_text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/diary_reddot_txt_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timesheetsreddotIMG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_img_marginleft"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/timesheetsreddot_img"
                    android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timesheetsreddotTXT"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_txt_layoutwidth"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/timesheets_reddot_txt_margintop"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/timesheets_reddot_text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/timesheets_txt_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/labelHZ"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/label_hz_margintop"
                android:gravity="top" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myjobTXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myjob_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/myjob_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/myjob_txt_margintop"
                    android:text="@string/myjob"
                    android:textColor="#35617d"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_myjob"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/diaryTXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/diary_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/diary_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/diary_txt_margintop"
                    android:text="@string/diary"
                    android:textColor="#35617d"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_diary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timesheetsTXT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/timesheets_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/timesheets_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/timesheets_txt_margintop"
                    android:text="@string/timesheets"
                    android:textColor="#35617d"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/label_timesheets"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectionBTN"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/section_btn_layout_hight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_btn_layout_margintop"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/myjobBTN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dairyBTN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/timesheetsBTN"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/nextjobRL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sectionBTN"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nextjob_rl_margintop" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/jobsectionbackgroundIMG"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_height"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginleft"
                    android:background="@drawable/job_section_background_2x"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/jobsectionbackground_img" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/jobsectionRL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobIMG"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_img_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_img_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nextjob_img_margintop"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/nextjobIMG"
                        android:src="@drawable/orange_arrow_right" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobTXT"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nextjob_txt_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_txt_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nextjob_txt_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_txt_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nextjob_txt_margintop"
                        android:text="@string/nextjob"
                        android:textColor="#35617d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/nextjob_txt_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl1_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl1_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl1_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl1_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl1_margintop"
                        android:text="@string/nextjob_txt_lbl1"
                        android:textColor="#35617d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/nextjob_txt_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL1"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl2_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl2_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl2_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl2_marginleft"
                        android:text="@string/nextjob_txt_lbl2"
                        android:textColor="#35617d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/nextjob_txt_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL1"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl3_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl3_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl3_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl3_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl3_margintop"
                        android:text="@string/nextjob_txt_lbl3"
                        android:textColor="#35617d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/nextjob_txt_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL3"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl4_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl4_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl4_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nextjob_txt_lbl4_marginleft"
                        android:text="@string/nextjob_txt_lbl4"
                        android:textColor="#35617d"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/nextjob_txt_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/detailsBTN"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/details_btn_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/details_btn_height"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL2"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/details_btn_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_btn_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/details_btn_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/details_btn_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_btn_margintop"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/detailsBTN_description"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_orange_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailsTXT"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/details_txt_height"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobTXTLBL2"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/details_txt_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/details_txt_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/details_txt_marginright"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/details_txt_marginleft"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_txt_margintop"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/details_txt"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/details_txt_size" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/you_dont_currentlyTXT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_margintop"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/you_dont_currently_txt_description"
                    android:text="@string/you_dont_currently_txt"
                    android:textColor="#35617d"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/you_dont_currently_txt_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lastjobRL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nextjobRL"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lastjob_rl_margintop" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/jobsectionbackgroundIMG2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/jobsection_background_img2_height"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginleft"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginright"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/jobsection_background_img_marginleft"
                    android:background="@drawable/job_section_background_2x"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/jobsectionbackground_img" />
</RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Can Anyone guide on how to align the views which are out of the visible area of the graphical layout.
Not able to insert whole xml code as character limit exceeds.

Comment: have you created `layout-landscape` folder??

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes i have created 'layout-land' folder.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138982/view-entire-content-of-scrollview-in-eclipses-graphical-layout

Or other than that, you may choose a tablet view(Such as Nexus 10) in graphical layout, or you may make some views invisible, align other views and make all visible again